# Text on top of image works without Z-index, why?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I want to display a subtitle text, running over the top of an image, aligned to the bottom (of the DIV containing the image).

I was expecting I'd need to use Z-Index but for some reason it works without. I'd really like to understand why.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="latest-item">
            <img src="images/latest-image-placeholder.png" alt="latest-image-placeholder"/>
            <div class="latest-item-copy">Bad schools, flawed justice create crime. Test Bad schools, flawed justice create crime. Test </div>
        </div>
```

And here's the corresponding CSS:

```
.latest-item    {
            height: 130px;
            background-color: fuchsia;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            }

.latest-item-copy   {
                width: 220px;
                /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
                background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
                /*  RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
                bottom: 0px;
                position: absolute;
                padding-left: 5px;
                padding-right: 15px;
                padding-top: 2px;
                padding-bottom: 4px;
                box-sizing:border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
                -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* Safari */
                font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                line-height: 18px;
                color: #F1F1F1;
                font-weight: bold;
                }
```

And here's what it outputs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdl9l.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you position an item absolutely, it pulls the element out of the document flow. It's the same thing that happens when you float an element. They automatically get placed in a different "layer" that has a higher z-index.

Comment: Yup, this was a clearer than my answer, you should accept this.

Comment: No problem, and thanks for the plug elclanrs. As to your second question OllyF, any element that's positioned absolutely is limited by the nearest parent that is positioned relatively. In other words, it's position is calculated based on that particular parent's box.

Comment: Thanks again, I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: No worries, that's why we're all here.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `position: absolute`

Comment: Thanks @elclanrs.

If I understand correctly, the text div is ignoring the image and positing itself absolutely at the `bottom: 0px` of the containing DIV.

And, in turn, the `position: absolute` only works because of `position: relative`. Can you explain why that is?

Furthermore, why is the text always rendered on top of the image,  what determines that?